# Best compression algorithm for Url query string

Tags: url, compression, base64, deflate

I have to pass a large url query string, so when this string size exceeds a certain number of characters, it creates problem when passed in the url.

Currently I have tried **deflation + base64 encoding**, which is giving me around 30-35% compression.

So if my query string becomes too large, say 4400 characters, it will be compressed to approximately 2650 chars, which wont fit to my url.

**I need a solution that gives better results than this one.**
I searched a lot, but not able to find a better solution.
Any suggestions on what else could be done will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Example of my query string:**

3d7821d1-e324-4cea-9bd7-763c0b62cdc2|94db7bdb-5e16-4700-a1f9-408ba7f7bee1|63360a17-0807-45a0-a798-31eb2614b0f7|9b37f302-2757-40e5-b9b4-390e5b786010|46ef6bce-c7e9-47d6-90d8-bc7c2b5784c0|e5f450a5-724b-42a0-aff9-34be2d50f59b|33db4e6b-bc53-4774-8267-759167a8dba9|30a8c7a9-0a3b-4df3-ab01-5e9b262d1902|d31086bb-98e8-41d0-a6cf-0bd48986bce7|30f27de5-1536-483a-85aa-6eb5000ba67b|41498746-3f45-4c16-9152-a6ca8355d502|6b5c643b-03f6-4390-9d54-79bf978f8e15|4537e3ba-09ed-465a-aad8-1c842084c3af|ad1161ab-0393-4a66-a538-6dda0c7b892a.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the solution- **deflation + base64**, doesnot completely solve my issue but improves the situation, so I integrated it with my code.

And for Future work, thinking about:

- Converting the request to POST 
  OR
- Taking sequential ids (1,2,3...), instead of UUID 
  (the example of query string shows that it is a concatenation of UUIDs)
  and concatenating, and passing in GET request.